# Ansible delegate and run_once

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i write one specific roles for local and dev environment that will drop and recreate the database from first server in dbserver group which mostly used as the master database.

```
group_vars/dbserver

[dbserver]
vagrant1 # master db
vagrant2 # slave db
```

after that, if i need to drop the database and also create the database again, basically i just need that command to be run on the first server in the group.

```
- name: drop database
  mysql_db: name={{ targetdbname }} state=absent
  when: targetdeploydb == "new"
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ groups.dbserver }}"
  run_once: true

- name: create database
  mysql_db: name={{ targetdbname }} state=present
  when: targetdeploydb == "new"
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ groups.dbserver }}"
  when: targetdeploydb == "new"
  run_once: true
```

Here is the log when i run the playbook

```
TASK [laravel : drop database] *************************************************
changed: [vagrant1 -> vagrant1] => (item=vagrant1)
changed: [vagrant1 -> vagrant2] => (item=vagrant2)

TASK [laravel : create database] ***********************************************
changed: [vagrant1 -> vagrant1] => (item=vagrant1)
changed: [vagrant1 -> vagrant2] => (item=vagrant2)
```

Another way that i can think of is by using the master db hostname directly on delegate_to but it means i need to create another variable. in the other hand, i think it would be better to reduce the number of variable and make it more dynamic. Please advise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to delegate your task to the first server only and run it once no matter how many servers in the current play, use:

```
- name: drop database
  mysql_db: name={{ targetdbname }} state=absent
  when: targetdeploydb == "new"
  delegate_to: "{{ groups['dbserver'] | first }}"
  run_once: true
```

Comment: Perfect! it's really working now and running only on 1 server. Anyway, do you know where i can read more documentation on advanced usage of ansible variable? I am not really familiar on when to use square bracket or curly bracket, even on how to use pipe as you given above to get the first result in an array. Or Is it based on python?

Comment: Everything you need is: [Variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html), [Ansible Filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html), [Jinja2 Filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters). Curly brackets and pipes come from Jinja2, square brackets come from Python.